# Using CRANQ i get this error message saying "Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor."

Tags: blockchain

I'm advancing this tutorial and using CRANQ to develop this blockchain project:
https://youtu.be/Y89q6T1r1Yg?t=1414

[image: Main view]

When i press PLAY I get error message differing from the tutorial saying that:
"Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor."[image: In the deploy contract node]

I've confirmed that the data passed to the Factory compiler has correct providerUrl, privateKey, accountAddress, network and that they are passed down to the factory compiler which sends the output signal to factory deployer. I tried to google the error but got nothing CRANQ related as search results. What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue with the CRANQ version itself. The patch came today and this works correctly with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).